# How to hardcode a certificate fingerprint in a websocket / socket.io webapplication

Tags: ssl, websocket, socket.io

How do I get/verify the certificate fingerprint if I use socket.io over tls so I can use a different self-signed privatekey for the websocket than for the webserver.
Thanks :)